# Insert XML elements into HTML in a .RPT template

Tags: html, xml, excel, rpt

A program that I use (Tekla Structures) generates an Excel **.xls** file using a **.rpt** template which consists of **html** (and or **xml**).
The final file consists of tables with text data. I am able to edit the **html / xml** code of the template by modifying the **.rpt** template. What I would like to do is to force Excel to **freeze first n rows of the sheet**.

I have tried to add the following code to the **head** section of the template:

```
<script>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
<x:ExcelWorkbook>
<x:ExcelWorksheets>
<x:ExcelWorksheet>
<x:WorksheetOptions>
<x:FreezePanes/>
<x:SplitHorizontal>5</x:SplitHorizontal>
<x:ActivePane>2</x:ActivePane>
<x:TopRowBottomPane>5</x:TopRowBottomPane>
</x:WorksheetOptions>
</x:ExcelWorksheet>
</x:ExcelWorksheets>
</x:ExcelWorkbook>
</xml>
<![endif]>
</script>
```

After examining the generated file I can see that the added code is there, however it won't work until I remove the **script** tag in a text editor. Then, if opened in Excel, the rows are frozen as they should be.
The problem is that without the **script** tag **xml** lines won't apply to the template.

In other words, I as far as I understand I need to insert **xml** elements in **script/script** tags, however the same tags prevent the elements to work.

Is there an alternative way to insert the **xml** code without using the **script** tag?

Thanks in advance,
Nick